# MFC/C++ dynamic resizing in dialog which is child of another dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog, resize

I have a C++/MFC dialog, A, which I have enabled dynamic layout for several controls via the Resource Editor in Visual Studio 2019. This works with no problem. When I build and run A, the selected controls resize and move as I specified.

Dialog A "contains" dialog B, for which I have also enabled dynamic layout using the Resource Editor. By "contains", I mean the dialog class for B is a member variable of A. my code moves the window of B to the desired position in A (to the user, it looks like A and B are a single dialog, as B has no border).

The difficulty I am having is this: when the user resizes A by dragging on its edge, I need dialog B to also resize. I handle this by getting the notification `OnSize (WM_SIZE)` or `OnSizing (WM_SIZING)` from A, and then resizing B using `MoveWindow`. B then receives a `WM_SIZE` message and its size is changed, but B does not do its dynamic resizing. How can I get B to do the dynamic resizing programmatically?

I saw the technique of setting dynamic layout programmatically for each control, but I want to use the values I set in the Resource Editor for B. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would try calling `CMFCDynamicLayout::Adjust` for your dialog `B`; I suspect that MFC somehow hooks into the sizing process, and this is not happening for your child dialog.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein: This seems to work; dialog B now does apply resizing and repositioning of its controls, although I haven't checked yet whether the resizing and moving fractions are exactly what was specified in the resource editor. Tnx for your prompt and useful response.

Comment: You are welcome!